# Delete magento extension after setup

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I need to create an Extension for Magento that add a new field to article attributes. So far so good. The install-script is done and working.

But my problem is: When the setup is done there is no need to keep those setup files in my Magento setup.

So I want to delete it after setup finishes.

Is it possible to completly remove this extension programmatically?

Comment: Why do you need to delete it?  The setup script will only run once unless you change the module version number directly in the DB

Comment: it is just for keeping our live-directory clean.